# How to detect wifi status change when request wifi dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, wifimanager

```
private fun createBroadCastReceiver() = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        when(intent?.action) {
            //Todo 4.1 Detect Receiver
            // Todo If WifiSuggestions Connected,
            ACTION_WIFI_NETWORK_SUGGESTION_POST_CONNECTION -> {
                Timber.d("NetworkReceiver: ACTION_WIFI_NETWORK_SUGGESTION_POST_CONNECTION")
                if (intent.action.equals(ACTION_WIFI_NETWORK_SUGGESTION_POST_CONNECTION)) {
                    wifiStatus.value = 1
                }
            }
            // Todo Wifi Status Changed,
            WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION -> {
                Timber.d("NetworkReceiver: WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION")
                when(intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN)) {
                    WIFI_STATE_ENABLED -> {
                        Timber.d("WIFI_STATE_ENABLED")
                        //Enable Wifi,
                        if (intent.action.equals(ACTION_WIFI_NETWORK_SUGGESTION_POST_CONNECTION)) {

                        }
                    }
                    WIFI_STATE_ENABLING -> {
                        Timber.d("WIFI_STATE_ENABLING")
                    }
                    WIFI_STATE_DISABLED -> {
                        Timber.d("WIFI_STATE_DISABLED")

                        val intent = Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_WIFI)
                        intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                        context?.startActivity(intent)
                    }
                    WIFI_STATE_DISABLING -> {
                        Timber.d("WIFI_STATE_DISABLING")
                    }
                    WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN -> {
                        Timber.d("WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hi,
Unfortunately, we can't android 10 enable wifi programmatically.

I create BroadCastReceiver to detect wifi status.
When wifi disabled, try to request wifi dialog to user for turn on.
In this code, pop up wifi dialog but when user put button like Done or More, it can't detect.

For example,

1. wifi disabled
2. wifi dialog pop up(wifi switch status: off)
3. click Done button(when wifi switch status: off)

In this case, there will be no change in the screen until the user turns on the Wi-Fi.

Is there a way to detect when the user presses Done without turning on the wifi request dialog?

Comment: No, ```setWifiEnabled``` is deprecated in API level 29.

Comment: You can't if you target API level 29 or above. Even popular automation app Tasker had to [workaround](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/lihmm6/is_there_a_new_way_to_disable_and_enable_wifi/) it by letting user install another APK that target lower API level.

Comment: @GaneshMB Yes.. I request wifi dialog to user, but when user push done button without turn on, I can't detected it.

Comment: @RickyMo There may be such a way, but I don't want such a way.

Comment: So I got misleaded by your title. Your title asks how to turn on wifi, but your content is actually asking how to detect wifi status change. Please make your title accurate.

Comment: @RickyMo Okay, thank you for advice.